# Excel Macro VBA: How to allow ONLY double click as input on a specific column?

Tags: excel, vba, double-click

How can I make column 6 (F) and 13 (M) to accept inputs only when I double click, which means it should not accept any numbers, letters or symbols and even the "delete" button but double click?

The following is the code I have worked out:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Checking whether target cell is in third column
Select Case Target.Column
Case 6, 13

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2:F13, M2:M13")) Is Nothing Then Cancel = True

'Prevent cell going into Edit Mode
Cancel = True

'Changing font type of the cell
Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"

'Checking if target cell value is blank then inserting tick
If Target = "" Then
    Target = "a"
Else
    MsgBox "You cannot modify the cell."
End If
End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I just noticed that you set `Cancel` to be true in two place in your code. First in your IF statement, and also right after that. So the value of your `Cancel` is always true. Secondly, you don't use the value of `Cancel` to decide what action should be taken next.

Answer (score 0):

When the user types something into the Worksheet, the events that get fired is `Change` and `SelectionChange`. `BeforeDoubleClick` is only triggered when they double-click, so of course it doesn't run if they only type.

The easiest way to do what you want is to go to the Review tab > Protect Sheet, then Allow Users to Edit Ranges. The VBA is only to mark the checkbox in F2:13 and H2:13.